# 500 Internal Server Error when using Ajax in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to use ajax call in my blade view and post ajax data to controller to insert to database.

Here is my ajax:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <title>FormBuilder Editor</title>
  
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://formbuilder.online/assets/js/form-builder.min.js"></script>

      <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
  </head>

  <body>
      <div id="fb-editor"></div>
  
      <div id="saveToDatabase">
        <button id="saveBtn" type="button">Save To Database</button>
      </div>
  </body>

  <script>
     var formBuilder = $('#fb-editor').formBuilder();
   
     $("#saveBtn").click(function() {
      var mFormData = formBuilder.actions.getData(); //JSON data return

        console.log(mFormData);
   
      $.ajax({
          headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
       type: "POST",
       url: "save",
       data: {
            "mFormData":mFormData
          }
      }).done(function (msg) {
       alert("Data saved!" + msg);
      });
     });
    
  </script>
</html>
```

And here is my controller:

```
public function saveToDb(Request $request) {

    $data = $request->all();

    if($data) {
        Form::insertData($data);
    }

    return view('welcome');
}
```

And this is my insert function in Model:

```
public function insertData($formData) {
    DB::EnableQueryLog();

    $sql = DB::table('form')->insert(['formKey' => 'testForm2', 'formData' => $formData]);

    return $sql;
}
```

When I click on button save, this is error in Network XHR:
[image]

How I can fix this? Thank you very much!

Comment: Do you have any content in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: 500 internal error mean that there is an error on the server side, so you should try debugging your controller, maybe the table names are wrong?

Comment: 500 Internal error come if you have PHP error. Look your code and debug it.

Comment: I check my laravel.log file and it say: "[2019-06-03 07:36:18] local.ERROR: Non-static method App\Form::insertData() should not be called statically {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Non-static method App\\Form::insertData() should not be called statically at /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/FormBuilder/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php:20)
[stacktrace]"

Comment: add static on your function.` public statiic function insertData($formData)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling the inserData statically. so it should be

```
public static function insertData($formData) {
    DB::EnableQueryLog();

    $sql = DB::table('form')->insert(['formKey' => 'testForm2', 'formData' => $formData]);

    return $sql;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line:

```php
Form::insertData($data);
```

with this:

```php
app()->make(From::class)->insertData($data);
```

Or inject the Form model instance in the constructor if you prefer.
However, the way you are inserting is not [how models are meant to be inserted](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#inserts).

Comment: I tried your answer but it's not work. I just add static into my function in model and it's worked. Btw, thanks for your help!